# Can I setup Raid 1 after the system is already running

Tags: raid, software-raid

I just finished installing owncloud server using centos 7. My data is located at /var/xxx and I dedicated the hard drive/dev/sdb just for this /var directory. After a while, I decided that I wanted to make this sdb to be RAID 1. 
I tried to search in Google but many of them only say that we can create before we fill the disk. My question: is it possible to create RAID 1 without deleting the data so all the data still intact and can be used? If it can how to do it?

Comment: I think you can follow that tutorial for the raid installation on the already running system https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679943/196562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story: Yes... you can add a RAID to a system after the OS is already created.  No... it's not very easy... and no... you won't be able to do this 100% online.  No... you can't mix a RAIDed volume with a non-RAIDed volume.  i.e. you can't have a full file-system on sda1... and then ONLY mirror /var to sdb1.  You can re-partition sda to include a new partition for /var... and then mirror that new partition on sdb... OR... you can convert the entire disk sda into a RAID...and mirror it to sdb.

The easiest way to accomplish this is with a live-cd of some kind that will allow you to manipulate your filesystem while the OS isn't running.  Basically, what you'll need to do is to create the RAID, mount the RAID, move the files over to the RAID, modify the mdadm.conf and append the output from `mdadm --detail --scan`, modify the `fstab` to mount the new volume on boot... and then reboot.  Sounds simple right? ... unfortunately, you can run into lots of "gotchyas" along the way... which can make the process more difficult.

Comment: Let me complete my condition to make sure this can be done. My "/" , "/home" , "/boot" is in sda1, sda2, sda3. My "/var" is in my sdb1, I plan to add another hard drive (for example sdc1) just to mirror sdb1. So should I create the RAID in sdc1 first? or sdb1 (how to make RAID without removing old data)?

Comment: I would definately suggest creating the raid mirror (degraded with only 1 drive) on sdc (if that is the unconfigured disk) ... then copy all the files over to the new volume... then remove (or temporarily rename) the existing /var... then add the RAIDed volume to fstab & mount it.  reboot... make sure everything came back as expected... and then finally add sdb1 to the raided volume.  Wait for the mirror to rebuild... and you should be golden.

Comment: The idea since very make sense. However can you help how to just create 1 drive raid first then the other. From I got from http://www.tecmint.com/create-raid1-in-linux/ by issuing command mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[b-c]1 the command will directly hit both drive sdb and sdc can we hit one by one?

Comment: specify "missing" for one of the drives in the RAID.  i.e. `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdc1`... and after you're ready to add the /var partition to the array... (you'll need to change the partition type to linux-raid) just do `mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Also... remember that the partitions need to be the same size.  Standard RAIDs do not work with partitions of different sizes.

Comment: This method work flawlessly, although there are some tricky parts make me do this 3 times. Because of file permission and the file system. Make sure the file system is exactly the same, and when you do copy make cp -rp then everything works perfectly. Thanks TheCompWiz

Comment: I usually use `cp -dpRx` ... which keeps everything in-tact... and doesn't copy un-necessary bits.

Answer (score 1):

raid level gets defined before initial data usage. I beleive that you can not do this now.
Although there might be any other possibilities on which I am not familiar.